# How to join 5 tables MYSQL with specific condition

Tags: mysql, join

i have 5 tables below

tb_satker

```
kdsatker
1
2
3
```

tb_akun

```
akun | code
A    | 1
B    | 2
C    | 3
```

tb_simponi

```
kdsatker | akun | jumlah
1        | A    | 100
1        | B    | 200
```

tb_span

```
kdsatker | akun | jumlah
1        | A    | 1
1        | B    | 2
1        | C    | 3
```

tb_upt

```
kdsatker | akun | jumlah
1        | A    | 10
1        | B    | 20
1        | C    | 30
```

What i need is output to something like this

```
kdsatker | akun | simponi | span | upt
1        | A    | 100     | 1    | 10
1        | B    | 200     | 2    | 20
1        | C    | 0       | 3    | 30
2        | 0    | 0       | 0    | 0
3        | 0    | 0       | 0    | 0
```

I've try using sql fiddle but the result is not right (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e83ce7/10)

```
SELECT tb_satker.kdsatker,tb_akun.akun,tb_simponi2.simponi,tb_span2.span,tb_upt2.upt
FROM tb_satker
LEFT JOIN (SELECT kdsatker,akun,sum(tb_simponi.jumlah) as simponi FROM tb_simponi GROUP BY kdsatker,akun)
as tb_simponi2 ON tb_simponi2.kdsatker=tb_satker.kdsatker
LEFT JOIN (SELECT kdsatker,akun,sum(tb_span.jumlah) as span FROM tb_span GROUP BY kdsatker,akun)
as tb_span2 ON tb_span2.kdsatker=tb_satker.kdsatker
LEFT JOIN (SELECT kdsatker,akun,sum(tb_upt.jumlah) as upt FROM tb_upt GROUP BY kdsatker,akun)
as tb_upt2 ON tb_upt2.kdsatker=tb_satker.kdsatker
LEFT JOIN 
tb_akun ON tb_akun.akun=tb_simponi2.akun AND
tb_akun.akun=tb_span2.akun AND
tb_akun.akun=tb_upt2.akun
GROUP BY tb_satker.kdsatker,tb_akun.akun
```

Can anybody help me with the right idea??
Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner queries are all based on a two-part group by two parts... kdsatker and akun.
Since it is possible for any of the tb_simponi, tb_span, tb_upt can have any combination,
I would pre-union all possible combinations of those FIRST.  THEN, Join to the summary results.
and FINALLY get the akun and kdsatker components.  Something like...

```
SELECT 
        tb_satker.kdsatker,
        coalesce( tb_akun.akun, 0 ) akun,
        coalesce( tb_simponi2.simponi, 0 ) simponi,
        coalesce( tb_span2.span, 0 ) span,
        coalesce( tb_upt2.upt, 0 ) upt
    FROM 
        tb_satker
            LEFT JOIN
            ( SELECT distinct kdsatker, akun FROM tb_simponi 
                UNION
                  SELECT kdsatker, akun FROM tb_span 
                UNION
                  SELECT kdsatker, akun FROM tb_upt 
             ) AllKdAkun
                on tb_satker.kdsatker = AllKdAkun.kdsatker

                LEFT JOIN tb_akun
                    on AllKdAkun.akun = tb_akun.akun

                LEFT JOIN 
                (SELECT kdsatker, akun, sum(tb_simponi.jumlah) as simponi 
                    FROM tb_simponi 
                    GROUP BY kdsatker, akun ) as tb_simponi2 
                    ON AllKdAkun.kdsatker = tb_simponi2.kdsatker
                    AND AllKdAkun.Akun = tb_simponi2.akun

                LEFT JOIN 
                (SELECT kdsatker, akun, sum(tb_span.jumlah) as span 
                    FROM tb_span 
                    GROUP BY kdsatker, akun ) as tb_span2 
                    ON AllKdAkun.kdsatker = tb_span2.kdsatker
                    AND AllKdAkun.akun = tb_span2.akun

                LEFT JOIN 
                (SELECT kdsatker, akun, sum(tb_upt.jumlah) as upt 
                    FROM tb_upt 
                    GROUP BY kdsatker, akun) as tb_upt2 
                    ON AllKdAkun.kdsatker = tb_upt2.kdsatker
                    AND AllKdAkun.akun = tb_upt2.akun
```

No final group by at the outer level.

First level is your `tb_satker`.  There may (or not) be a record in any of the subsidiary tables, so that is first.

Second level is a distinct list of every `kdsatker, akun` in ANY of the other 3 tables.  So now you can LEFT JOIN `kdsatker` thus keeping every record including 1, 2, 3 even though 2 & 3 have no records.

From the second level, you can now left-join to the `tb_akun` table which in this case, only `kdsatker` is the only one with records for any given akun.

Finally joining the pre-union list of all combinations grouped by `kdsatker, akun` are able to be matched for their final summary into the final list.

Hope each step makes sense to what you appear to be trying for.